# Edimax Wifi and Chromium Kiosk mode

Tags: wireless, chromium

I used edimax usb wifi dongle for connectivity managed by WICD 
I also have chromium set to autostart in a kiosk mode and display a web page (status board - details of the setup [here](http://www.geckoboard.com/geckopi-run-geckoboard-on-a-raspberry-pi))

What happens if the browser is launched before the wifi is connected so an error is displayed in chromium because page could not be found due to lack of connectivity? Any ideas how to overcome this issue?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you want a way to prevent the browser to be launched before the Wifi is up?

Comment: @Morgan - that would be one of the solutions. Basically what i am after is that the dashboard page loads and does not require keyboard to refresh after wifi kicks in.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution i found. I created a local page and pointed chromium to is. From there javascript checks if the browser is on-line and if so it will redirect to the dashboard page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Dashboard Loader</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

</head>
    <body>
          Loading dashboard

    </body>
    <script>

        function loadDashboard()
        {
            if (navigator.onLine) {
                window.location.href = "https://demo.geckoboard.com/dashboard/B6782E562794C2F2";
            }
            else
            {
                setTimeout(loadDashboard, 1000);
            }

        }
        setTimeout(loadDashboard, 3000);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Good solution. But you could also edit the network start daemon script so that Chromium only starts after the network.

Comment: @Jivings can you give me some more detail - i am not much of a linux guy.

Comment: Your solution is fine :)

Comment: C'mon i wan to learn something. You are not being very constructive here :)